# i am new to python and i am messing around with it i want to know why isnt this program working?

Tags: python

i am messing around with custom functions but i cant make it work and i dont know how to make it work, i searched around a bit but still nothing seems to solve this problem.
i would be grateful if someone helped :)

i wanted to try making the random.randint() function shorter into r()
and thank you for helping me out.

i realized my mistake, i saw people using open() read/write commands i thought i understood how it worked, guess i thought wrong.

thank you <3

## **my code:**

```
import random as ra

def r(a,b):
    with open(a,b) as int:
        r = ra.randint()
    return

w = r(1,100)


print(w)
```

## **compiler says**

```
line 8, in <module>
    w = r(1,100)

line 4, in r
    with open(a,b) as int:


TypeError: open() argument 'mode' must be str, not int
```

Comment: Did you let some AI generate that code? Because it is absolute nonsense, nothing about it makes any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @luk2302 i have not used an ai i wrote this nonsense by myself

Comment: Then you need to rethink why you call the opened file `int`, why you open a file in the first place, why you pass 100 as the `mode`, why you generate a random number, store it in `r` and then never use it, always return `None` and then print that always `None`. Literally **nothing** of this makes any sense. Please follow a python 101 tutorial, something that covers the very first steps.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hey dont know why you want to use the open method
in your function you declare the variable and use return to get the value
since you are new to this ChatGPT is really helpful when it comes to easy stuff like this

```
import random as ra

def r(a,b):

    random_int = ra.randint(a,b)
    return random_int

w = r(1,100)


print(w)
```

Comment: hello man thank you, this helped me but i have just one question. can random_int be anything?

Comment: sure you can name it however you want its just good practise to name variables in a way that you are later easily able to understand what it does

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Answer (score 0):

open() function is used to open files, with the first parameter being a file path and the second parameter being a 'mode', typically 'r' for read, or 'w' for write.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score -1):

The line `with open(a,b) as int:` doesn't really make sense. `open` is used for reading files and `int` is a datatype.

Can you clarify what the function r is supposed to do? This would help us help you.

Answer (score -1):

The open function takes 2 positional arguments, The file and a mode, An example being :

```
with open("C:/Users/Alwma2/Documents/myfile.txt", "r") as file
    my_file = file.read()
```

The mode is telling the file system what you want to do in this case, In this example we used "r" to tell it that we will be reading from it, Other modes include "rw", "w", "b" and more.